# Handle DateTime in JPA2

Tags: java, datetime, jpa-2.0

I'm using JPA2 with EclipseLink implementation.
I'm simply trying to save the current Date into a **DateTime** column into a MySQL Database.

The date object which should be persisted is simply created:

```
import java.util.Date
Date currentDate = new Date();
```

Now the `currentDate` contains the exact date and time.
This object is persisted in a table which has the following column:

```
@Column(name="DATE_CREATED")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
Date dateCreated;
```

The `TemporalType` has three constants:

- `DATE` - this saves in the DB the date without any time: *(2012-02-23 00:00:00)*
- `TIME` - this throws an incompatibility error
- `TIMESTAMP` - this saves in the DB the date without any time: *(2012-02-23 00:00:00)*

The database column is created this way:

`date_opening DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,`

For all this options I'm failing in saving the both the time and the date.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Please post the exact definition of the table you are writing to. Maybe it uses a DATE column that does not hold a time?

Comment: dateCreated is of type java.util.Date, right? Not of type java.sql.Date?

Comment: @sleske I'm using MySQL. This is how I created the datetime column `date_opening` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,`. The column has time saving capability because some default `00:00` is displayed

Comment: @JBNizet Yes. dateCreated is `java.util.Date`

Comment: If you use TemporalType.TIMESTAMP on a mysql TIMESTAMP field, it works. However I'd expect to work also with TemporalType.TIMESTAMP on a mysql DATETIME field

Comment: @perissf Yes I know. It doesn't work properly. It saves the date but not the time. I think it's weird that there is no constant for `DATETIME` at all

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should work perfectly with TemporalType.TIMESTAMP and database column type DATETIME. Maybe you are checking type for wrong column: in mappings you have "DATE_CREATED" and in column definition "date_opening".

You asked also why there is no TemporalType.DATETIME. Reason is that values of TemporalType have one-to-one mapping to JDBC temporal types in java.sql.[DATE/TIME/TIMESTAMP], in the end JPA have to play together with JDBC.

I tested with following code (env: EclipseLink 2.3.0, Connector/J 5.1.6, MySQL 5.1):

Entity/mappings:

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(name="DATE_CREATED")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private java.util.Date dateCreated;

    public SomeEntity(int id, Date dateCreated) {
        this.id = id;
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }
    public SomeEntity() {
    }
}
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE  `test`.`SOMEENTITY` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DATE_CREATED` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=innoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Test:

```
java.util.Date now = new Date();
SomeEntity se = new SomeEntity(1, now);
em.persist(se);
```

It works as expected, also time part of DATE_CREATED is having correct value. If mismatch between columns was not the problem, maybe you can test this as well, and report results and MySQL and library versions.

Answer (score 1):

With the mapping :

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private java.util.Date dateCreated;
```

when you retrieve the data from MySQL - it gives something like :

1519621200000